# Get index of different element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to get the index of an div with id of clicked anchor:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#div1">Div 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#div2">Div 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#div3">Div 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="foo">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

So, if I click `Div 1` I want to get `.foo #div1` index, but I can't do this by myself.

I have tried:

```
$('ul li a').click(function() {
    var target = $(this).attr('href');

    // $(target).index();
    // $('.foo').index(target);
})
```

Thanks =)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the corresponding div in .foo with the same index as the one clicked on with this:

```
$('ul a').click(function() {
    // get the index of the item that was clicked
    var index = $(this).closest("li").index();
    // find that same index in .foo
    var target = $(".foo > div").eq(index);
})
```

Or, if you want to use the href, you can do it like this:

```
$('ul a').click(function() {
    // use getAttribute so we don't get a fully qualified URL
    var target = $(this.getAttribute("href"));
})
```

Or, another way to do it using a fully qualified URL:

```
$('ul a').click(function() {
    var target = $(this.href.replace(/^.*#/, "#"));
})
```

Comment: While this works, I think it's better to directly target the elements that'll be clicked. In this case, the `a` tags. If you go back to your code a month from now, this may not be as obvious as `$('li a').click...` in my opinion. Plus, what if you add some padding to `ul` or something else where the user can click on the `ul` but not the `a` ? Then you may be capturing clicks you don't want to.

Comment: @tptcat - I had already changed my selectors to the `a` tags before you commented.

Comment: first example `index` always return `-1`

Comment: @GabrielSantos - fixed the first example.  Works here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/UFDvu/.  I had optimized the selector, but forgot that it affected the `.index()`.  Fixed now.

Comment: @GabrielSantos - I'd have to see your exact code to see what the issue was because `$(this).closest("li")` works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/UFDvu/.

Answer (score 0):

You specified the ID attributes incorrectly.

Lose the hash symbol from the `id` attributes, but not from `href` ones. Then your second attempt will work.

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up a bit:

```
$(function() {
    $('li a').on('click', function() {
        var target = $(this).attr('href');
        $('.foo ' + target).html('hello');
    });
});
```

I put the event handlers directly on the `a` inside the `li`. I've also used jQuery's `on()` method introduced in 1.7 which is the preferred way for event handlers.

then:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#div1">Div 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#div2">Div 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#div3">Div 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="foo">
    <div id="div1"></div>
    <div id="div2"></div>
    <div id="div3"></div>
</div>
```

To get the index of the clicked item:

```
$('.foo ' + target).index();
```

jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/DNfYg/

Comment: There's no advantage for `.on()` over `.click()` when using normal event handling directly on the object (not delegated event handling).  Also, there's no reason to do `.foo #div1` as the selector when `#div1` will work just fine and be faster.

Comment: I know hot to get the target and populate, for instance. Now, I want to know hot to get the index of the target.

Comment: No advantage, but it's consistent and is the preferred method, which is all I stated. Plus, if later on he decides to dynamically add some `li`'s then this code will work. `click()` will not.